# How to display CPU and GPU fan speed percentage (instead of RPM) during gaming?

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, vga, gaming, msi-afterburner

I use MSI Afterburner, RivaTuner and HWiNFO to (on screen) display CPU & GPU temperatures during gaming, but these softwares are not able to display the fan speeds in percentage. They only show RPM and I'm not able to change RPM to % in their settings.
**Is there a way to show fan speed in % with these softwares?

Or is there another software for it?**

Please let me know. RPM values are quite useless when I have 6 fans and all of them have different maximum RPM values. I simply cannot memorize their maximum speed and calculate the percentage all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that CPUID HWMonitor has the functionality you are looking for. Here is a [link to their download page](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html).

Comment: HWMonitor does not display any information about fans (on my laptop anyway).